# Meaning of 無理に聞いても 言わせてもね

Tags: phrases, manga

I encountered the phrase in a slice-of-life manga:

```
無理に聞いても 言わせてもね
```

The first half I can understand, roughly "even if you force them to say it", but the second part 言わせてもね does not make sense to me and dictionary (like Jisho) did not help. Contextually it would mean, I guess, that "even if you (try to) force them to say it, they won't say it anyway". Is this right?

This is the snapshot:
[image]

The context is basically that Koizumi telling a complicated story about her family to Shino, who has a complicated family issues of her own (and Shino thought she managed to move a bit towards resolving it).

Comment: without the whole scene is hard to give a more accurate answer, but it could more in the sense of "you can force someone to say something, but you cannot force then to mean / feel it"?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the two phrases do with each other. Do you have previous context? (a picture would be more welcome)

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Is this enough? I tried taking a snapshot that hopefully gives enough.

Comment: @Everiana Thank you. Perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, the second phrase is just a loose self-restatement.

> まあ　無理に聞いても　言わせてもね
> lit. "Well, even if (I) ask (her) forcefully... even if (I) make (her) say (forcefully), don't I"
> *Well, no use extracting it... forcing her to say it...*

Ending a sentence with Vても usually implies "V doesn't help" or "V makes no good".