# でもね sentence ending

Tags: grammar

From Oshi no ko ch. 38,

[image]

For context, these guys saw the debut of a new group named B小町. They recall hearing about a group of the same name.

I am confused about the function of でもね at the end of the sentence 名前が同じでもね. I suppose it is an inverted sentence. It is supposed to mean でもね名前が同じ?

Comment: Essentially the same as https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80473/45489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「名前だけ同じでもね」

can imply something like

> 「名前だけ同じでも（違うメンバーだよ）ね。」
> 「名前だけ同じでも（違うメンバーなら見る価値がないよ）ね。」
> *Lit.* "Even though just the name is the same, (it's not the same band,) you know."

This is not an inverted sentence / 倒置, but an omission / 省略. The latter half of the sentence is left out as implied.

The first person is saying the name is the same but it is a different band so may not be worth watching, so the second person says まあ一応ちょっと見て帰るか (*Lit.* Well let's have a quick look just in case and go home.)

Answer (score 0):

I think they are saying:

> 名前だけ同じでもね - But, only the name is the same, right?
>
> まぁ一応ちょっと見て帰るか - Hmm, anyway should we see it a bit and then go back?

The sentence is **not** inverted. They are **not** asking if the name is the same (名前が同じ?), they are certain the name is the same. The first guy is saying that only the name is the same, i.e. it might be a totally different band in reality (or not). So the logic behind they words could be:

First guy:

> [There's a new band]/[There's this band B小町], **but** (でも) they are only similar in name [to the band we recall], **right?** (ね)

He thinks it doesn't necessarily mean they are going to enjoy this band just because they liked the original B小町, and he is looking for agreement by the second guy.

Second guy

> Maybe, let's see

He (kind of) acknowledges first guy's assessment and proposes to give this band a try.